# Is it possible to read data from a local port using Javascript or ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**I written the following to broadcast a data in a Windows Application using C#**

```
 UdpClient server = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", 9050);

            string welcome = "Hello, are you there?";
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
            server.Send(data, data.Length);
```

**But, How can I read the same data by a web application using javascript or asp.net?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a webservice or wcf service. Javascript can be serialized into JSON.  Have a look at the [json](http://www.json.org/) website to check out the syntax.  I have used [JQuery](http://JQuery.com) to do the ajax communication to call the webservice in the past.  The all you need to do to convert this back to a javascript object is

```
var myObject = eval(myTransferObject)
```

Comment: I am able to send this message successfully without any errors. I need to read back that posted message with javascript code.